# Output next character after specific key (regex)

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I made a simple text with random characters and a pattern. After every **xw'4** there is a character I want to output, for example, gi563ngni**xw'4A**ge38gre. "A" is the character I'm looking for. What would be the best command to print it? I'm working in Ubuntu Terminal console.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `grep` with perl-regex might work for you:

```
grep -oP "xw'4\K." file
```

Comment: Thank you it is working. I was trying with egrep "xw'4" but didn't know how to proceed, I also used grep -oP with simple examples, but I was not getting this result.